# Consecutive Combine Publishers. Isolating business logic in a Simple Sign In flow example

Tags: swift, combine

I'm quite new to `Combine` and, instead of running all my tasks into the `viewModel`, I'm trying to better isolate the code that has to do with business logic.

Let's take a `SignIn` service as example. The service receives `username` and `password` and return `token` and `userID`.

The exposed call of the service is `signIn` that internally calls a private func `networkCall`. I'd like to implement the two functions to return a `Publisher`. 
The role of `networkCall` should be calling the API and storing the received token, while the role of `signIn` is only to return a success or a failure.

This is my code, where I'm also highlighting where I'm getting stuck.
In general I don't know where is the right place to work with the information received from the API (and store the token). At the moment I'm doing it inside a `.map` call but it sounds wrong to me. Could you share some advice to improve this logic and especially explain which is the right place to run the business logic... I'm supposing that `.map` is not the right place! and `.sink` will just stop the chain.

```
struct SignInResponse:Codable{
    var token:String
    var userID:String
}

class SignInService {

    // Perform the API call
    private func networkCall(with request:SignInRequest)->AnyPublisher<SignInResponse, ServiceError>{
        return URLSession.DataTaskPublisher(request: request, session: .shared)
        .decode(type: SignInResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .mapError{error in return ServiceError.error}
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func signIn(username:String, password:String)->AnyPublisher<Result<String, ServiceError>, Never>{
        let request = SignInRequest(with username:username, password:password)

        return networkCall(with: request)
            .map{ (response) -> Result<String, ServiceError> in

                if response.token != ""{
                    // THIS SOUNDS EXTREMELLY WRONG. I SHOULD NOT USE MAP TO HANDLE THE TOKEN -------
                    self.storage.save(key: "token", value: response.token)
                    return Result.success(response.userID)
                }else{
                    return Result.failure(ServiceError.unknown)
                }
            }
            .replaceError(with: Result.failure(ServiceError.unknown))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    ...... 
}
```

From the model I call SignIn in this way:

```
func requestsSignIn(){

    if let username = username, let password = password{
        cancellable = service.signIn(username: username, password: password)
            .sink(receiveValue: { (result) in
                switch result{
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
                case .success(let userID):
                    // the sigin succeeded do something here

                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I agree with the existing answer. Your misconception here seems to be what a Combine pipeline is for. The idea is that *either* a useful value — here, your  user ID — *or* an error (if appropriate; otherwise, nothing) should pop out the end of the pipeline. The subscriber at the end of the pipeline stands ready to receive either of those.

Thus it generally makes no sense to pass a *Result* object out the end of the pipeline, which must be further analyzed into a success or failure value. The goal of a Result object is merely to allow you to pass asynchronicity around, i.e. by handing someone else a completion handler to be called with a Result at some future time, just so as not to have to call with one of *two* values, i.e. either a real value or an error, using two Optional parameters.

Once a Combine publisher has published, though, asynchronicity has *already* happened, and you're getting the signal of this fact; that's what publishing *means*. The only thing you now need to preserve is whatever part or mutation of the signal is meaningful and useful to you.

Here is a fairly typical pipeline that does the sort of thing you want to do; I have not divided this into two separate pieces as you do, but of course you can divide it up however you like:

```
    URLSession.DataTaskPublisher(request: request, session: .shared)
        .map {$0.data}
        .decode(type: SignInResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .tryMap { response -> String in
            if response.token == "" {
                throw ServiceError.unknown
            }
            return response.userID
        }
        .receive(on:DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {err in /* do something with error */ },
              receiveValue: {userID in /* do something with userID */})
        .store(in:&storage)
```

First, the result of a data task is a tuple, but all we need is the data part, so we map to that. Then we decode. Then we check for an empty token, and throw if we get one; otherwise, we map down to the user ID because that is the only useful result. Finally we switch to the main thread and capture the output using a sink, and store the sink in the usual `Set<AnyCancellable>` so that it persists long enough for something to happen.

Observe that if at *any* stage along the way we suffer a failure error, *that error* is immediately propagated all the way out the end of the pipeline. If the data task fails, it will be a URLError. If the decoding fails, it will be an Error reporting the issue, as usual with a decoder. If the token isn't there, it will be a ServiceError. At any point along the way, of course, you can catch and block or transform the error as it comes down the line if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative setup have `signIn` return a publisher with just Output `String` and Failure type `Service.Error` directly (the `Result` type becomes redundant with a Publisher).

Then, for an error like an empty token string in the response, use `tryMap` instead of `map` to transform the `Result` type from network function and have it throw an `ServiceEror.emptyToken` or something like that. That will cause the publisher to publish that as the Failure right away.